# firefox width of elements different to webkit-browsers

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, css

I think its easier for you to inspect elements instead of me writing the code so here's the link = [music band site](http://test.tobiasekman.com/solitude). Now the problem:

The in chrome everything works fine, but if u make the window smaller(width) in firefox you'll see that the social-icons dont stick to one row (as they do in chrome) in the yellowish socialbar. Why is that?

Also the socialicons in the Footer gets to a new row in firefox, but not in chrome. Whyy?

thank you! (yes i know the pics are too big and more stuff will be fixed later.)

Comment: add a `min-width` or `width` to the wrapper

Comment: cant do that, because the wrapper need to have different widths (%). its responsive

Comment: it's fluid rather than responsive

Comment: ye, thats a better word

Answer (score 1):

You can move the padding you have on the `#socialbanner a` selector onto the `#socialbanner img` selector:

FROM:

```
#socialbanner a {
    padding: 0 1.275%;
}
```

TO:

```
#socialbanner img {
    padding: 0 1.275%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```